# Why won't my background video play on mobile? (Rails app)

Tags: ruby, html, video, ruby-on-rails-5, html5-video

I have a fullscreen background video that plays at the top of the page when it loads.  It works fine on desktop but when I try it on mobile I get the play button with a line through it.

I tried moving the video to a server and when I go to the video url directly it works on my phone.  Just not showing up in the app.

```
%section.first
    .video
      = video_tag 'reel.mp4', autoplay: true, loop: true, controls: false, muted: true
```

I'm using rails and testing on an iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had to add

```
playsinline: true
```